# Why does this NSTimer crash?

Tags: objective-c, nstimer

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5al6qqRzzQg when i click on the start more than once???
what will i need to do

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@implementation FirstViewController

-(IBAction)start;{

    myticker = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(showActivity) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
-(IBAction)stop;{ 

    [myticker invalidate];
}
-(IBAction)reset;{

    time.text = @"0";
}
-(void)showActivity;{ 

    int currentTime = [time.text intValue];
    int newTime = currentTime + 1;
    time.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", newTime];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
```

Comment: -1 : No crash log. No error description. There's not even a crash in that video.

Comment: If you actually read the code, the problem is obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your start and stop methods to this:

```
-(IBAction)start;{

    [myticker invalidate];
    myticker = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(showActivity) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(IBAction)stop;{ 

    [myticker invalidate];
    myticker = nil;
}
```

That will stop it crashing. Also, you should add this:

```
-(void)dealloc
{
    [myticker invalidate];
}
```

Comment: hi mate thanks for that it works but were do i put the -(void)dealloc
{
    [myticker invalidate];
}  and what does it do ???

Comment: just put it in your view controller. It ensures that when your view controller is released, your timer doesn't keep going.

Comment: Yes, you need to invalidate the timer in this case. But NO, you do not need to add `[myticker invalidate]` in the dealloc. This is pointless. Since the timer retains the target you will never get to the dealloc until it is valid. And other way round, the fact that dealloc is called means retain count is zero, so the timer is already invalidated.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I guess it's more just a safety precaution in case the target for the timer is ever changed to something else.

Answer (score 0):

add a bool variable to the header of your class, like timerIsActive

```
-(IBAction)start;{
if (!timerIsActive) {
    myticker = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(showActivity) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
  timerIsActive = YES;

}
}

-(IBAction)stop;{ 
    timerIsActive = NO;
    [myticker invalidate];
}
```

Comment: @implementation FirstViewController

-(IBAction)start;{
    if (timerIsActive) {                    
     myticker = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(showActivity) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        timerIsActive = YES; 
}        
}
 
        
-(IBAction)stop;{ 
    timerIsActive = NO;
    [myticker invalidate];
}
-(IBAction)reset;{
    
    time.text = @"0";
}
-(void)showActivity;{